# Apache echarts Treemap: set selected tree node and zoom to node after data refresh

Tags: javascript, angular, zooming, treemap, echarts

**Environment:**

- OS: Windows
- Browser: Google Chrome
- Framework: Angular@14
- Library: Echarts@5.4.0

**Reproduction Link:**
https://jsfiddle.net/AimanKhan11/51kuv2mc/11/

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. run the fiddle
2. drill down to specific node (click event will store the last visited
   tree node info into variable)
3. click on refresh button

**Current Behavior:**
By clicking on refresh button, treemap not zooming to last visited node and going to its initial state.

**Expected Behavior:**
Treemap should zoom to last visited node and maintain its state after refreshing options.

```
const chart = echarts.init(document.getElementById("chart-container"));
let lastVisitedNode;
chart.setOption({
responsive: true,
maintainAspectRatio: false,
series: {
  name: 'All',
  type: 'treemap',
  visibleMin: 300,
  leafDepth: 1,
  sort: null,
  roam: 'move',
  drillDownIcon: '',
  label: {
    show: true,
    formatter: '{b}',
    padding: 5
  },
  upperLabel: {
    show: true,
    height: 30,
    padding: 5
  },
  visualDimension: 1,
  levels: [{
      itemStyle: {
        borderColor: '#555',
        borderWidth: 4,
        gapWidth: 4
      }
    },
    {
      colorSaturation: [0.3, 0.6],
      itemStyle: {
        borderColorSaturation: 0.7,
        gapWidth: 2,
        borderWidth: 2
      }
    },
    {
      colorSaturation: [0.3, 0.5],
      itemStyle: {
        borderColorSaturation: 0.6,
        gapWidth: 1
      }
    },
    {
      colorSaturation: [0.3, 0.5]
    }
  ],
  data: [{
    "value": [
      32,
      32
    ],
    "name": "HEADWEAR",
    "path": "HEADWEAR",
    "children": [{
      "value": [
        12,
        12
      ],
      "name": "HEADWEAR",
      "path": "HEADWEAR>HEADWEAR",
      "children": [{
          "value": [
            1,
            1
          ],
          "name": "WHT",
          "path": "HTG>WHT",
          "children": [{
            "value": [
              1,
              1
            ],
            "name": "Travel/Commute",
            "path": "HTG>Travel/Commute",
            "children": []
          }]
        },
        {
          "value": [
            1,
            1
          ],
          "name": "CMO",
          "path": "BLK>CMO",
          "children": [{
            "value": [
              1,
              1
            ],
            "name": "Fitness",
            "path": "BLK>Fitness",
            "children": []
          }]
        },
        {
          "value": [
            1,
            1
          ],
          "name": "HBK",
          "path": "CMO>HBK",
          "children": [{
            "value": [
              1,
              1
            ],
            "name": "Fitness",
            "path": "CMO>Fitness",
            "children": []
          }]
        },
        {
          "value": [
            1,
            1
          ],
          "name": "HTG",
          "path": "HTA>HTG",
          "children": [{
            "value": [
              1,
              1
            ],
            "name": "Fitness",
            "path": "HTA>Fitness",
            "children": []
          }]
        },
        {
          "value": [
            2,
            2
          ],
          "name": "HTA",
          "path": "HBK>HTA",
          "children": [{
            "value": [
              2,
              2
            ],
            "name": "Fitness",
            "path": "HBK>Fitness",
            "children": []
          }]
        },
        {
          "value": [
            6,
            6
          ],
          "name": "BLK",
          "path": "HEADWEAR>BLK",
          "children": [{
              "value": [
                1,
                1
              ],
              "name": "Travel/Commute",
              "path": "Outdoor>Travel/Commute",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "value": [
                1,
                1
              ],
              "name": "Outdoor",
              "path": "Fitness>Outdoor",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "value": [
                4,
                4
              ],
              "name": "Fitness",
              "path": "HEADWEAR>Fitness",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
  }],
  nodeClick: 'zoomToNode',
 },});
chart.on('click', function(params) {
  if (params.seriesType == "treemap") {
    lastVisitedNode = params;
  }
});
if (lastVisitedNode) {
 // zooming to specific node programatically is not working 
 setTimeout(function() {
   chart.dispatchAction({
     type: 'treemapZoomToNode',
     seriesIndex: 0,
     dataIndex: lastVisitedNode.dataIndex,
     //name: lastVisitedNode.name,
   });
   chart.dispatchAction({
     type: 'highlight',
     seriesIndex: 0,
     dataIndex: lastVisitedNode.dataIndex,
     //name: lastVisitedNode.name,
   });
   console.log('dispatch action');
 }, 2000)
}
```